# Why can I use initializer syntax with readonly properties

Tags: c#

I have a `Manager` class with two properties as below:

```
public class Manager()
{
  private string _name;
  private List<int> _reportingEmployeesIds;
  public string Name { get { return _name; }}
  public List<int> ReportingEmployeesIds { get {return _reportingEmployeesIds; } }
```

I am trying to create an instance of the `Manager` class as follows

```
Manager m = new Manager 
{  
   Name = "Dave", // error, expected
   ReportingEmployeesIds = {2345, 432, 521} // no compile error - why?
};
```

The set property is missing from both the properties but the compiler allows setting `ReportingEmployeesIds` whereas does not allow setting the Name property (Error: Property or indexer Manager.Name can not be assigned to, it is readonly).

Why is this the case? Why doesn't the compiler complain about the `ReportingEmployeesIds` being readonly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ReportingEmployeesIds = {2345, 432, 521}` doesn't *set* the property. It is shorthand for calling `Add(...)` with each of the items. You can always `Add`, even for a readonly list property.

For it to be a *set* it would need to be:

```
ReportingEmployeesIds = new List<int> {2345, 432, 521}
```

Instead, the line:

```
Manager m = new Manager {Name = "Dave", ReportingEmployeesIds = {2345, 432, 521} }
```

is essentially:

```
var m = new Manager();
m.Name = "Dave";
var tmp = m.ReportingEmployeesIds;
tmp.Add(2345);
tmp.Add(432);
tmp.Add(521);
```

Comment: Is `m.ReportingEmployeesIds` really saved in `tmp` variable, but not accessed each time you call `Add`?